# Memory, swap and mysql config requirements for importing a 50GB sql table?

Tags: mysql

**Update:**

Mysql cannot be started up now after the import failed once again, despite making the changes suggested by both answers below.

```
tail /var/log/syslog
Jul 10 01:13:48 homestead kernel: [64517.537149] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-6): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 20 (offset 8388608 size 4194304 starting block 17079280)
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead mysqld[25025]: Unable to determine if daemon is running: Success
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1978.
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jul 10 01:13:49 homestead env[1039]: [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
```

**Original post:**

How would one calculate/determine the best settings for memory, swap and a good mysql configuration?

I've been attempting for several days now to import a 50GB sql table into a database on my local machine within a virtual machine (an Oracle VM VirtualBox specifically). This has been given 12GB base memory (out of my pcs 16 max) and 2 processors (out of my pcs 4 max).

No matter what I try to import the database it will come back with mysql has gone away errors, and then I can no longer connect to mysql as innodb is trying to recover itself over-and-over again in the background.

**I can tell that this issue is a MEMORY related issue**, since more records get imported before it crashes as I add more memory allowance.

- I've attempted to give 30GB of SWAP but it still crashed!
- The table.ibd file (in /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase) got to 58GB in size on my last attempt)

Not sure what to try next, other than giving up and re-exporting the table with the --skip-extended-inserts flag.

My current mysql config while doing the imports:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

[mysqld]
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 7G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
key_buffer_size=2G
max_connections=1000
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=256K
query_cache_min_res_unit=2k
query_cache_size=200M
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=16M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
```

After it fails I can see by running "top" command that mysqld process exists and that innodb recover is being attempted over and over with this command:

> `sudo strace -e trace=read,write -s 2000 -fp $(pgrep -nf mysql) 2>&1`

FYI, I run a query to dump the table like this:

> mysqldump -h localhost --user=user --password=password mydatabase
> my50gbtable --hex-blob --single-transaction --quick
> --max_allowed_packet=999M --compress > my50gbtable.sql

**I appreciate any ideas you might have!**

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE my50gbtable; from the server hosting the table.  innodb_log_buffer_size should NEVER be larger than innodb_log_file_size.  Swap the values. Make query_cache_type=0 and query_cache_size=0 and query_cache_limit=0 and query_cache_min_res_unit=512. REMOVE sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size, please.

Comment: Are you making any progress?  If any comments or suggestions helped you, please upvote or Accept, if possible to make us aware of your progress.

Comment: I needed to upload the database on my local machine rather than a virtual machine (I believe this is due to limited specs on the virtual machine) and make sure that wait_timeout and interactive_timeout were set to a higher value. I also used HeidiSQL to manage importing the SQL file, which eventually worked. I'd say the issue is my machine is just not powerful enough, so when uploading on an even more-limited virtual machine, it would fail.

Comment: My advise for anyone facing a similar situation is to take a close look at your system specs and ensure that they are plenty!

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use `--single-transaction` to dump the data. On import, the MySQL server will have to keep the entire contents of the table in memory during the import until it's committed, thus defeating the purpose of options like `--quick`.

Dump the database without using `--single-transaction`.

Comment: Ok - I removed this and re-exported and attempted the import again. It still does not complete however it does seem to be importing for a while. I'm seeing that, mid-query, mysql keeps saying "No connection. Trying to reconnect... ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket" :(

Comment: During the import not the dump. I can dump the table/database just fine without issues.

Comment: Hm, you've probably got other problems. Check MySQL's logs to see why it is crashing.

Comment: The mysql error log is filled with these: tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
2020-07-10T01:17:52.394196Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 47687424000

Comment: @NAMAssist I just saw that you posted log entries showing disk I/O errors. You should stop trying to import this database, and identify and replace your failing hard drives first.

Comment: The hard drives are virtual drives on an Oracle VM? Not sure how to look into/begin fixing these sorts of issues?

Comment: These disk i/o errors happen each time I try to import the database and it fails, actually.

Comment: If this is a virtual machine then you need to look at the storage being provided by the VM hypervisor. If you don't admin the hypervisor you need to speak to whoever does.

Comment: Hmm. I am simply running this virtual machine on my own computer at home. I use a Vagrant box. Don't have any experience with these so I guess I'll be stuck at this.

Comment: Surely you can replace a hard drive?

Comment: Yes. I'll try moving the vm to another drive first. I suspect the drive failures are occurring due to something else with my setup. There are no issues importing SQL files about half the size of this one. Will update this when my new attempts are done. Thanks

Comment: So I tried a couple other drives. This made no difference. The query imports a large amount of the data, then fails and I see a flood of messages about not being able to connect to local mysql server through socket. I can then no longer start mysql and need to destroy the vm since I can't find any solutions to revive mysql either. Sigh... might have to resort to using --skip-extended-insert and bigdump, or try importing the database on a different machine altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Which Engine?  It should be InnoDB.  In this case, you don't need to waste 2G on the `key_buffer_size`; set it to only `20M`.

`innodb_log_buffer_size = 2G` -- This is just a buffer; it does not need to be huge, and making it this big simply wastes ram.  Go back to the default (or, say, `16M`).

You say "base" memory of 12GB.  What does "base" mean?  If you really have 12 for the VM (OS+mysql, and nothing else), then your setting of 7G for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is good.

`max_connections=1000` -- another space waster.  The loading will use only one connection, so the default (which might be 151) is fine.

`query_cache_size=200M` -- another space waster.  It won't help the loading *at all*, and it wastes RAM.  Most systems are better off with `0`.  The Query cache is unavailable in clustering environments and in MySQL 8.0.

No swap space should be necessary.  (That is, it is optional.)  Since you are crashing, something is not as it seems.

Comment: I've tried making these changes, but as-per my response to the above answer, it's still not working unfortunately.